# With an ItemWriter which persists all of my value objects, is it possible to perform a separate db insert only once?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have an implementation of an ItemWriter which persists all of my value objects nicely.  When the first value object (for the batch job) is passed to the ItemWRiter can I perform a separate db insert, and guarantee that this insert will not occur for subsequent value objects coming into the ItemWriter?

Apologies it sounds wordy.  In simpler terms I want to get a record to a status table to show that the batch job has started writing and not have this inserted n times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JobExplorer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html) to query SB metadata tables and check if step is started.
Another way: you can use a listener like the [`ItemWriterListener.afterWrite()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemWriteListener.html) and store your flag into audit table (and - also - into execution context to prevent multiple writes).